# Delphi Executable starts in debug mode

Tags: delphi, ide

Whenever a Executable is opened,  the delphi IDE opens as like debug mode. what settings has changed in my IDE?

Can any one help me!

Update: 1. Build taken in other machine also causing this issue. 
How come a opening an EXE, starts the IDE?

2. Default debugger was modified from vcjitdebugger to delphi debugger. So in case of exception delphi instance was started. It can me modified as below:

You need to delete the following registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger
On a 64 bit system delete this key also:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of your IDE, you have a combo box with the available layouts of the IDE.
You probably have ‘Debug layout’ selected instead of ‘Default layout’ or so...

[image: IDE Layout selection]

When you have opened a project, select 'Default layout' and then it will persist that choice for the next time you open a project.